# Add to cart doesn't show up

Tags: inventory, stock, quantity

I imported several products (multi language and imported one run into the English store and one run into the German store).
Now the quantity field and the add to cart button won't show, eventhough I already tried several option for Inventory:

Manage Stock: No
Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 10
Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart: 100000 (use config settings)

But even if I switch to manage stock yes and put like 100 products in stocks nothing changes on the products.
I even flushed the cache.
Do I need to reindex anything?
What else could it be?

Found one more example - manage stock yes and still 2 in stock.
On the German website I can't buy it (no add to basket button) but on the English version I can buy it.
Is there another setting somewhere not at the product where this problem could come from?
The product/inventory settings for the store views are identical.

[image]

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes after the import?

Comment: Yes - several times already. The import is like 3 months back but the stocks changed (I did it manually now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:
On an import I had the column for the add to cart thing "Block after info Column" not set properly (has been mixed up with translations).
I reimported it and now it works. :)